# In the clojure source code, what does RT stand for?

Tags: clojure

clojure / src / jvm / clojure / lang / RT.java

The above seems to be one of the most important source files in clojure source code. For the sake of understanding the architecture, what does the RT stand for?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

RT stands for Run-time.