# What does IFn in Clojure stand for?

Tags: java, clojure

In the Java source code for Clojure, I have seen:

```java
import clojure.lang.RT;
import clojure.lang.IFn;
```

`RT` seems to stand for "run-time" (although no official source is given in the answer: [In the clojure source code, what does RT stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980119/in-the-clojure-source-code-what-does-rt-stand-for))

But what does `IFn` stand for?

Comment: `IFn` is the interface that all compiled Clojure functions comply with. A call to a Clojure function compiles into a call on one of the many `invoke` methods of its `IFn` interface.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*IFn* means **I**nterface **F**u**n**ction. Clojure uses the capital "I" prefix for Java interfaces and "A" for Java abstract classes.

See also [IFn Javadoc](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/javadoc/clojure/lang/IFn.html) and [IFn source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IFn.java)

Answer (score 5):

in clojure's terms there is also one more difference between `fn` and `ifn`:

```
user> (defn f [x] x)
#'user/f

user> (map fn? [f #(list %) :keyword 'sym {:a 10} #{123} [1 2 3] 10 "asd"])
(true true false false false false false false false)

user> (map ifn? [f #(list %) :keyword 'sym {:a 10} #{123} [1 2 3] 10 "asd"])
(true true true true true true true false false)
```

so, as you can see `fn?` is true for actual functions only, while `ifn?` if true for anything, that could be **called as a function** (like keywords, maps e.t.c)

Comment: The distinction that "`fn?` is true for actual functions only" is misleading. `:keyword` is just as much an "actual function" as `#(list %)`. A more correct statement would be that [`fn?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/fn_q) tests whether something is of the type of object which is returned by [`fn`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/fn).

Comment: :keyword is as much actual, if we talk about it's *callability*, but still, its type is `keyword`, so it's obviously not a function.

Comment: Sorry, but no. It's correct to say that a keyword is not a member of Clojure's concrete `Fn` type, but it's counterproductive to say that `Fn`, rather than `IFn`, determines whether something is an "actual function". [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6916532/5044950) does a good job of explaining this viewpoint.

Comment: Sorry, but you haven't convinced me. "Something with function's semantics" and "function" are different things. First of all on the code level: when you see a hashmap in source code, you don't think that it's a function, rather you say "a hashmap, that can be used as a function". That was my point. And by "actual function" i really mean "anonymous or bound lambda expression". So with these terms in mind it is as correct, as saying in Fn/IFn types terms. Anyhow, it is rather useless to argument about that.